# How do you install custom commands in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to install additional commands besides the standard ones, such as these:

```
/spawn                  player's spawn to spawn
/jail                   player spawns to a jail 
/kit ...                player receives specific items 
/join mob arena         player joins mob arena
```

and so forth. How do I go about adding these to my server?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? its a legit question and its not answered anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

- You need a Bukkit Server: [Bukkit Download](https://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/)
- You need Essentials Plugin: [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/)

If you need a Tutorial: [How to set up a bukkit server](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/guide-how-to-set-up-a-bukkit-server.148041/)

Then you can use commands like this on your Server. There are many Plugins, Essentials only have the "standart" ones. You can search for others here: [Most downloaded Plugins](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/downloads) or here [Plugin List](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/)

Also you can make Signs with Essentials to teleport to a speciffic place: [Sign Tutorial](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/Sign_Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create commands like this you need to know how to write bukkit plugins. If you know how to do that, then you cash create these custom commands. It would be cool to see a feature like this in-game though..

Answer (score 0):

- You need a server that supports plugins, not vanilla minecraft servers but servers like spongepowered. https://www.spongepowered.org/
- Then after you installed the server you can add the plugins that you need in the plugins folder.
- Install [EssentialCmd for Sponge](https://forums.spongepowered.org/t/essentialcmds-v8-1-14/8576)

Finished

Currently no plugins as MobArena at Sponge yet...